# Need Help in Xamarin UI Test

Tags: user-interface, testing, xamarin

> Upload failed. Response: Status: 400 Contents: {"error_message":"The
>   .ipa file does not seem to be linked with Calabash framework."}

how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Call `Xamarin.Calabash.Start()` in your `AppDelegate` of your iOS project. See below:

> **Initialize the Xamarin Test Cloud Agent**
>
> After adding the Xamarin Test
>   Cloud Agent to the iOS project, it is necessary to initialize the
>   Xamarin Test Cloud Agent when the iOS project starts up. Edit the
>   AppDelegate class and add the following snippet to the
>   FinishedLaunching method:
>
> ```
> // Newer version of Visual Studio for Mac and Visual Studio provide the
> // ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD compiler directive in the Debug configuration,
> // but not the Release configuration.
> #if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD
>    Xamarin.Calabash.Start();      
> #endif
> ```
>
> The Xamarin Test Cloud Agent must not be present in a release build of a Xamarin.iOS application; its presence is grounds for the
>   app to be rejected by Apple. By surrounding the initialization code in
>   a conditional compile statement, the Xamarin linker will strip the
>   Xamarin Test Cloud Agent from Release builds, but not Debug builds.

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/adding-uitest/#Initialize_the_Xamarin_Test_Cloud_Agent

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because I had the wrong test framework selected in my build pipeline.  I had `XamarinUI Test` instead of `XCUITest`.